# How to upload file to directory that is up from home directory using FTP in RCurl?

Tags: linux, r, windows, ftp, rcurl

I need to upload a file using FTP in R, but the directory is up from my home directory on the server. When I run the following code using RCurl, I get this error: `550 var: No such file or directory`:

```
ftpUpload(what = "./plots/daily/LastTwentyFour.png",
      to = "ftp://spider/../../var/www/dashboard/img/LastTwentyFour.png",
      verbose = TRUE,
      userpwd = "REDACTED:REDACTED")
```

More specifically, I get this output:

```
> PWD
< 257 "/home/dhadley" is the current directory
* Entry path is '/home/dhadley'
> CWD var
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 550 var: No such file or directory
* Server denied you to change to the given directory
* Connection #0 to host spider left intact
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
Server denied you to change to the given directory
```

It works when I try to upload to my home directory:

```
ftpUpload(what = "./plots/daily/LastTwentyFour.png",
      to = "ftp://spider/LastTwentyFour.png",
      verbose = TRUE,
      userpwd = "REDACTED:REDACTED")
```

I guess the question is, how do I navigate between directories within the ftpUpload function? Or, if there is another way to upload a file from Windows to a Linux server in R, I am open to that too. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I have write access to the directory in question, and am able to upload files in FileZilla. I cannot change my home directory on the server, unfortunately.

Comment: Are you able to upload files to that directory with another program besides R?  I'm guessing the answer is no and that there is a permissions/ownership issue.

Comment: Oh I just realized that the ".."s in that path are intended to get out of the home directory and on to root.  As @MrFlick said, for this to work you'd need to setup the server's home directory as "/" instead of "/home/dhadley" and as he further points out, you probably shouldn't do that.  Besides this point, why did you tag windows in your question?

Comment: @Dean, I'm sorry: I should have also mentioned that I have write access to the ../../var/www/dashboard directory. I can access it in FileZilla. It's where we store the part of our website that I work on.

Comment: @Dean I can't change my home directory on the server, unfortunately. I added Windows in case anyone has a suggestion other than RCurl on how to move files in R, but that may have been to bland of a tag. Thanks.

Comment: you're saying FileZilla will let you specify /var/ww/dashboard essentially as /home/dhadley/../../var/www/dashboard?

Comment: @Dean, yes that seemed to work. Normally, when I access through FileZilla I just use the GUI to click `..` until I get to `var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a FTP server to test this on but something like

```
ftpUpload(what = "./plots/daily/LastTwentyFour.png",
  to = "ftp://spider/var/www/dashboard/img/LastTwentyFour.png",
  verbose = TRUE,
  userpwd = "REDACTED:REDACTED", prequote="CWD  /var/www/dashboard/img/")
```

The prequote argument should pass the command `CWD` (change working directory) to the server before it tries to interact with the given path.  The reason filezilla works is because when you double click the '..' in the gui, it is sending the FTP server a CWD command.

Comment: thanks so much! adding 'CWD /var/www/dashboard/img/' in the `prequote` worked first time.